# React.addons.classSet is not a function React js

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs

I am using react js and i am getting

> React.addons.classSet is not a function

error in the following code.

```
dayClassName: function dayClassName() {
return React.addons.classSet({
  "day": !this.props.day.filler,
  "filler": this.props.day.filler,
  "today": this.isToday()
});
},
```

I am getting this error on second line on return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html) `React.addons.classSet` is deprecated. The recommended alternative is [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames).

For reference, beware [addons are experimental](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/addons.html) and this behavior may repeat in the future.

Comment: I am using a plugin which is already build in react with jsx files i had converted it in js using Babel. I am not aware of reactjs in deep so i just want run this piece of code .

Comment: This is not jsx-related, but an utility plugin baked for React. If you have little knowledge of what it does exactly, I suggest you dropping the plugin and figure out for yourself until you know exactly what you need.